# Вызов меню по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку появлялось меню с возможностью выбора на подобии ListView, но чтобы не создавалось новое Activity, а было что-то вроде AlertDialog. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;

PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);
popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "Пункт0");
popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Пункт1");
popup.show();
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
              switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                     case 0: 
                           //code
                           break;
                     case 1:  
                           //code  
                           break;
                    }
              return true;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если дело в User Expirience, то таки создайте новую активность и установите для нее диалоговую тему( "Theme.Dialog", например ). После чего загрузите внутрь разметку с ListView и вы добьетесь нужного эффекта.

Если же новую активность категорически не хочется добавлять в проект, то вам на помощь придет класс **[Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)** со своим методом [`setContentView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setContentView(int)), благодаря которому вы сможете загрузить внутрь разметку и взаимодействовать с ней.